# While using nodejs, How can I access files outside root directory?

Tags: html, node.js, express

I'm making a nodejs page to show as an management page.
I need to access a directory outside root directory.
But I can't access with relative path.

Directory example is like this.

C:\resultDirectory\projectA

C:\resultDirectory\projectB

C:\reportDirectory\ProjectA

C:\reportDirectory\ProjectC

C:\NodejsRootDIrectory

What I want to do for now is Access a file in subdirectory of "C:\resultDirectory\projectA". But at the end, I need to access them all. So I can't make webpage root to project A's directory.

What I've dont to access was relative path. sample is 
        $('#report').load("../../../ProjectA/Daily/DailyReport_191001_151843.html");

I've checked number of "../" and tried add and subtract several times.

For now, this is only code relative to access files.

$('#report').load("../../../ProjectA/Daily/DailyReport_191001.html");

When I check chrome's error, there is only 404 error. the browser can't find out the file I want to see.

Comment: Node.js does not provide access to ANY files on your server automatically. You have to provide an Express route that gives access to serving a file. If you want to give access to a whole directory of files, you can use a route with `express.static()` to provide access to a whole directory of files. You should NEVER provide any type of access that would allow a web browser (or any snoop) to get access to your node.js server code files so you have to be careful how you expose directories with `express.static()` typically only exposing leaf directories that are purposely crafted for public access

Comment: Thank you very much for hint and advice. I'll check it.